# Posicionamiento sin guardar la posición inicial en el documento

Tags: css, angularjs

tengo un problema con el posicionamiento de 3 div. Utilicé *position:relative* pero guarda la posición inicial en el documento y no me interesa. Con la *position: absolute* me desaparecen partes de los div y probé con *transform: translate()* pero también me guarda la posición inicial. 
El *float* creo que no me sirve porque necesito flotar un div al centro y no existe *float:center* 
Qué puedo utilizar para colocar los div y que no me quede guardada la posición inicial en el documento? 
Gracias de antemano.

Codigo html:

```
  <div class="cal-day-hour div1" ng-repeat="hour in vm.hourGrid track by $index" ng-if="$index>=0 && $index<=7">
    <div ng-repeat="segment in hour.segments track by $index">
        <strong ng-bind="segment.date | calendarDate:'hour':true"></strong>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="cal-day-hour div2" ng-repeat="hour in vm.hourGrid track by $index" ng-if="$index>=8 && $index<=15">
    <div ng-repeat="segment in hour.segments track by $index">
        <strong ng-bind="segment.date | calendarDate:'hour':true"></strong>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="cal-day-hour div3" ng-repeat="hour in vm.hourGrid track by $index" ng-if="$index>=16 && $index<=20">
    <div ng-repeat="segment in hour.segments track by $index">
        <strong ng-bind="segment.date | calendarDate:'hour':true"></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Los 3 div, necesito poner uno a la derecha, otro en el medio y otro a la izquierda.

Comment: Sin código es difícil ayudarte. Agrégalo a tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que no te quede guardada la posición inicial en el documento?

Comment: Buenas Francisco, pues me refiero a la posición natural en el documento, es decir a la posición que tendria según el orden que esté en el html. Con _position:relative_ puedes mover el div o  lo que sea pero sigue manteniendo la posicion natural, "el hueco" en la página. Eso es lo que no quiero, busco algo que mueva el div y no mantenga la posición natural.

Comment: Podrias usar Bootstrap, con la clase col-xs-3, o bien usar float left en el primero, float right en el segundo y el del medio deberías ponerlo en el último lugar sin un float

Comment: podrías poner un diagrama o algo de lo que tienes y lo que quieres conseguir